# Impact of fixing on the valuation of derivatives

Tags: interest-rate-swap, valuation, cross-currency-basis

I would like to know what is the impact of a fixing on the value of a fixed vs floating interest rate swap (IRS). Also, I have the same question about the fixing impact on a cross currency swap?

On a fixing date, does the value of the swap decrease ? Is there any change in the interest rate sensitivity?

Comment: Unclear what you mean !

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear what you are asking.
On fixing date, the floating leg has a duration that is approx. the duration of a ZCB with maturity equal to the next payment.
Anyway, the pricing of the floating leg is always the discounting of forward rates so the fixing date has not a direct impact on the price but rather on the interest rate sensitivity.